# How to fix Wine/Bottles error "Unable to load libGLX_nvidia.so.0"

Tags: nvidia, wine

When I run programs in Wine using Bottles, I get the message: `(ERROR) Unable to load libGLX_nvidia.so.0`.

I do have an Nvidia card.

What causes this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: https://github.com/bottlesdevs/Bottles/issues/2690

Comment: @ChanganAuto There does not seem to be an actual solution at that link, just somebody deciding to close it because "it's not really a bug". It also looks like that person has an AMD card, which is different from my issue.

Comment: Have you installed the 32-bit nvidia libraries though? (e.g., in Arch, `lib32-nvidia-utils`)

Comment: @TomYan Yes, I did